# weird character appeaaring when connecting another server over ssh on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, ssh

The following string appears in terminal:

```
]133;C;]133;D;0]1337;RemoteHost=root@ubuntu.letbox.com]1337;CurrentDir=/root]133;Aroot@ubuntu:~#
]133;B
```

it seems to tell me the current directories along with weired characters like `]1337`  .
Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: what is "another device"? These are control characters that should be interpreted by your terminal.

Comment: Possibly a malformed prompt string (`PS1`) defined in the remote environment?

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by someone setting up iTerm2 shell integration as per http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html.

Check to see if .iterm2_shell_integration.bash is being sourced by .bash_profile. This just happened to me logging into a Ubuntu server, I fixed it by removing ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash.

Also noted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292042/how-to-fix-shell-prompt-ps1-after-remote-login